# Change color of StrikethroughSpan

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the color of `StrikethroughSpan`?

I've already tried `TextPaint`, but it seems that it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

defining the foreground TextView or defining Paint Flag

**Through PaintFlag**

This is the simplest method you just have to set strikethrough flag on your TextView as,

```
yourTextView.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add two CharacterStyles to the region, e.g.

```
textView.setText("blah blah", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) textView;
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 5, 8, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), 5, 8, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: For people testing this code: `ForegroundColorSpan` in this case changes both: the color of the text and the color of the strike-through line.